# Get attribute of class by directly accessing instance

Tags: python, class, call, instance

I was wondering how one can "call" an instance of a class such that the instance itself returns a specific value, attribute or method return.
I try to make that clear with an example:

```py
import numpy as np

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = self.x*2
        self.z = self.x*3


    def __call_instance__(self):
        return np.eye(2)*self.x


def some_function(x, y, z):
    return x, y, z


inst = MyClass(3)

some_function(x=inst, y=inst.y, z=inst.z)

Out[1]:
(array([[ 3.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  3.]]), 6, 9)
```

I know that I can define `__call__()` as a method and call an instance by `inst()`. But is there a way to use the return of a specific method or a certain attribute by just "calling" the instance without the parantheses? In other words, so that the instance itself acts like an attribute/property of itself?
I hope that if could make it clear what I'm searching for :-)

I'm looking forward to your answers.
Cheers and thank you in advance.

Markus

Comment: Nope, and what you're proposing is highly unlikely to ever be added to the language.

Comment: **...by just "calling" the instance without the parentheses**.  That makes no sense.  The call *is* when you add the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, i know. I just didn't know how else to express it :-)

Comment: No, there isn't, and it sounds highly unadvisable to want that. Don't be lazy, just write the stupid parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a way to use the return of a specific method or a certain attribute by just "calling" the instance without the parenthesis?

By typing the instance name, without anything else, you are simply asking for the instance (more precisely, you are asking for the value of the variable that is binded to the instance). You have a variety of methods you can invoke - calls to override operators, printing override by `__str__`, invocation by `__call__`.

**But how would you expect to access the instance, if you override it's name for one of its methods?**

---

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l = l.pop
# How can you access the original list?
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responds. Ok, I think I get the point. So, I guess I have to override some of the operators, like __add__ etc.